# RabbitMQ - Intermittent etimedout error between two EC2 instances

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I have two Ubuntu EC2 instances in the same availability zone and security group. A web server is running on Server A and it passes requests for long-running jobs back to Server B via RabbitMQ using [php-amqplib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib).

RabbitMQ server is running on Server A. Server B is listening to the queue on Server A.

Most of the time, the system works as expected. The user does an action on the web server (Server A) which enqueues the job into the queue, and Server B receives the message and does the job. In these cases, the RabbitMQ log shows the request being serviced within a second:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 29-Nov-2016::00:07:11 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.31632.2> (###.###.###.###:51968 -> ###.###.###.###:5672)

=INFO REPORT==== 29-Nov-2016::00:07:11 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.31632.2> (###.###.###.###:51968 -> ###.###.###.###:5672)
```

However, I intermittently get an `etimedout` error when performing the same request:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 28-Nov-2016::21:56:51 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.21543.0> (###.###.###.###:56827 -> ###.###.###.###:5672):
{inet_error,etimedout}
```

How can I debug this issue? I've confirmed that Server A's RabbitMQ port appears to be open when running `nmap` on Server B, and the setup works part of the time. Any ideas on how to debug the failure case?

Answer (score 1):

it's possible that the Amazon networking infrastructure is forcefully closing an "idle" connection between your servers.

Try adding a heartbeat to your connection configuration. This will force the connection to remain active, even when there are no messages moving between servers.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html

A 30 second heartbeat may be sufficient. You could go lower if you need to. I'm not sure how EC2 determines an "idle" connection, though.